# WP_Query Custom Post type, with specific categories

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a WP_Query which will loop into a custom post type and give me results in the specific categories only.

The print_r of my final query string is

```
(
    [post_type] => portfolio
    [post_status] => publish
    [paged] => 1
    [posts_per_page] => 60
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => portfolio_category
                    [field] => term_id
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 229
                            [1] => 219
                        )

                    [operator] => IN
                )

        )

)
```

This works fine, but it is showing all posts with either category 229 and 219. I don't want to show that, I want to show posts which are both in 229 and 219. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your tax_query operator to `AND`.

> operator (string) - Operator to test. Possible values are 'IN'(default), 'NOT IN', 'AND'. [Source: Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 229, 219 ),
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but didn't use it. I had to rush so followed a more complicated solution of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110360/category-and-for-custom-taxonomy :(